# "/sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=3" - Permission denied as root

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, operating-system, debian

I am having some issues with the cache. It is 4Gb so I wanted to clear it. I googled and found this little command:  /sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=3.
I am logged in as root over SSH (not using sudo). These are the attempts I made:

```
root@usve83005:~# /sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=3
sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.drop_caches'
```

It is a remote machine running Debian.

I really just want to clear the cache

Comment: duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109496/echo-3-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-permission-denied-as-root
and even **don't clear** the pagecache unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: when I do free -m i see some memory cached. Will this affect any computation on the system?

Comment: Yes. It will speed up read i/o jobs when in cache. If the system needs more memory, the pagecache will be freed first. It's not your job, it's the kernel's job.

Comment: But, if I ran the same command on the local system, it worked fine for me.